# Drupal import Tweets from Twitter as Nodes

Tags: drupal, twitter, drupal-6

I want to be able to import my tweets from twitter into Drupal as Nndes. I want to be able to link `@names` and `#tags` back to the correct pages. I also don't want myTweeterName to appear at the start of the tweet.

How would you go about doing this? The twitter module does not create nodes but stores data in its own table. The feed module can read in the tweets from the RSS feed as nodes, but will display my name and not link `@names` and `#tags`.

The following post by [Gábor](http://hojtsy.hu/blog/2009-dec-17/highlighting-some-tweets-my-blog-experiments-feeds#comment-1115) shows how he has done it but I am not sure  how he has written a custom module to do this.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gabor is using the [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) module along with the input filter from the twitter module.

From his post:

> Tweets have certain special items like
> @username references and #hashtags.
> These should be linked to their
> respective twitter.com pages, and
> twitter module has input filters for
> these which I could use to build up an
> input format. (Given my use case, I
> had no use for the rest of the twitter
> module, so I took the format code into
> my site-specific module, and do not
> actually use twitter.module.) The
> twitter feed also includes my username
> at the beginning, which my site
> readers will either know or do not
> care about, so I also wrote a quick
> filter which will transform my
> username to a "from twitter" link at
> the end of the node body.

You'll need to start importing your tweets using the feeds module. Then you'll need to add the input formats from the Twitter module to your default import (probably "Filtered HTML").

Comment: You'll need to start importing your tweets using the feeds module. Then you'll need to add the input formats from the Twitter module to your default import (probably "Filtered HTML").

Is the bit where I was getting lost> I wil give it a go.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible any more, as Twitter does not export the user timeline as an RSS feed

Comment: Should still be possible (via the API), just a fair bit more work! :(