# Import into Drupal 7 Twitter posts with a specific hashtag (using Twitter API 1.1)

Tags: drupal, twitter

I want to import into Druapl 7 all Twitter posts (from all users) with one or more hashtags that I chose. Since Twitter has updated to API 1.1, most Drupal modules no longer work. Is there any updated module to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Twitter widgets show posts (embedded code) and nothing else. I want to import Twitter posts into Drupal nodes and store them

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drupal import Tweets from Twitter as Nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990317/drupal-import-tweets-from-twitter-as-nodes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by properly setting up a few dev modules, specifically these:

feeds, >= 7.x-2.0-alpha8+56-dev

feeds_oauth, >= 7.x-1.0-beta3+2-dev

feeds_jsonpath_parser, >= 7.x-1.0-beta2+12-dev

along with a custom app you setup at dev.twitter.com

I've posted a more complete answer at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/107615/pulling-hashtags-and-displaying-them-on-site/136136#136136

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the standard twitter widgets and just embed the code wherever you'd like it displayed. You can create a new one here (including hashtags): https://twitter.com/settings/widgets/new/search